# Start timer on button click not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

I tried to implement a button to start a timer when it is clicked but it doesn't seem to work.
This is the code I used. It only starts when the page is loaded but I want to set the button click to activate the timer. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$("#startClock").click(function() {
  startTimer();
});

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time1');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
  <div>Timer : <span id="time1">05:00</span></div>
  <div class="mdl-grid">

    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

    <button id="startClock" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
      50 coins 
    </button>

    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are invoking `startTimer();`, Although `startTimer` expects to have two arguments which you didn't pass.

Comment: So how do I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make sure you're passing the parameters to `startTimer()`, in this case `fiveMinutes` and `display`:

```js
$("#startClock").click(function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time1');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
  <div>Timer : <span id="time1">05:00</span></div>
  <div class="mdl-grid">

    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

    <button id="startClock" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
      50 coins 
    </button>

    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Additionally, you may want to rework your interval function a bit to fire it off as soon as you click the button (And doesn't wait a second before it starts counting down):

```js
$("#startClock").click(function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time1');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
    
  var intervalFn = function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  };
  
  
  setInterval(intervalFn, 1000);
  
  intervalFn();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
  <div>Timer : <span id="time1">05:00</span></div>
  <div class="mdl-grid">

    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

    <button id="startClock" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
      50 coins 
    </button>

    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: OMG. It actually worked. I will keep that in mind next time! But what about disabling the button whilst the timer is running?

Comment: Sorry man: This website isn't all about doing everything for you. Give it an attempt, and if you can't get it working then you can come back here when you run into a road block, or investigate/research further on your own.

Comment: But why does the timer start again when it ends?

Comment: Because of your last line: `if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I am new to Javascript so I am finding it very hard to cope. Using a project to learn it. I find that quicker.

Comment: The problem is, if you don't do the basics, and you jump right in, you can get overwhelmed very easily: Which is what is apparent here. I recommend picking up a book, learning the syntax/quirks as well as a jQuery guide/tutorial. It will help go a long way to making your life a lot easier. If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted, by hitting the green checkmark to the left of the post.

Comment: I upvoted please. But I tried something else with this code to clear the timer after it run out. if (--timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }; But it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: `clearInterval()` should take in the return value from `setTimeout()`. `timer` is an integer here, and contains the number of seconds run. You need to assign a variable from your `setTimeout()` function, and pass that into `clearInterval()`.

Comment: So can I use intervalFn as the variable?

Comment: Lol I will do some research. Thanks